# Regular expression for durations

Tags: javascript, regex

I am exploring regular expression and I have tried to match the following pattern using the mentioned regular expression in javascript

Pattern : `0 to 23h OR 0 to 59m` 

Example : Expected strings : 0h upto 23h OR 0m upto 59m 

Regex : `/^(([0-1]?[0-9]h|2[0-3]h)|([0-5][0-9]m))?$/`.

It verifies the 0-23h successfully but fails for 0-59m. I guess something goes wrong in the way the `OR` operator is used between `0-23h` and `0-59m`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match here? Because that doesn't match `"0-23h"`, `"0-59m"`, or `"0-23h OR 0-59m"`. If you mean `0-59` as in a number between 0 and 59 such as `25m`, then you aren't matching single digits such as `9m`. So add `([0-5]?[0-9]m)`

Comment: `regex` is not the most appropriate tool for this job. It can be used to match the numbers and then the usual JavaScript comparison operators can be used to verify that the numbers belong to the desired ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments. The reason is because your regex for minutes:

```
[0-5][0-9]m
```

Always matches two digits, so it will fail for: `0m`, `1m`, `2m`, ... `9m`. To fix that simply add a `?` after `[0-5]` so it can be optionally ignored:

```
[0-5]?[0-9]m
```

Entire Regex:

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9]h|2[0-3]h)|([0-5]?[0-9]m))?$
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this regex:

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9]h|2[0-3]h)|([0-5]?[0-9]m))?$
```

tested here: https://regex101.com/r/exDcKs/2

however notice that with this regex

```
00h or 0h
01h or 1h
02h or 2h
03h or 3h
04h or 4h
05h or 5h
06h or 6h
07h or 7h
08h or 8h
09h or 9h
```

are both accepted and this is the same for the minutes!!!
In order to reject timestamps starting with a `0` like `01h` or `01m` use the following regex:

```
^(([0-9]h|1[0-9]h|2[0-3]h)|([0-9]m|[1-5][0-9]m))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/exDcKs/3